# Mailing List Logic With Cascading Dependencies

Tags: list, recursion, logic, cascading, mailing

I am making a mailing list program that a user is able to build logic sets to include contacts that meet the criteria. Similar to how HubSpot creates mailing lists if you have ever used them. For example: 
[image: HubSpotExample]

When criteria are added, the list gets refreshed via a backend job to come up with WHO is in the list. These are saved to the DB as a relationship table for quick reference by the application later Eg (List_ID & Subscriber_ID columns.

The issue I am running into is how to handle when a List includes logic that says Include Subscribers from another list.  For example if List A logic says Include users from Maryland.  And List B says Include all members from List A.  When you make a change to List A to also include Florida for example, List B should then also be updated, because it is a dependent of A. Keep in mind there could also be other logic on either list as well. Or logic pointing to other lists that also include other lists as well!
So then you could also have situations where lists are pointing at eachother and run into some type of circular or recursion situation. 
Any ideas on the best way to handle this? I would also thing the ORDER that you have to update the list and dependent lists is of importance as well.